# Is having a single massive class for all data storage OK?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have [created a class](https://projectavian.com/AviManager.as) that I've been using as the storage for all listings in my applications. The class allows me to "sign" an object to a listing (which can be created on the fly via the `sign()` method like so):

```
manager.sign(myObject, "someList");
```

This stores the index of the element (using it's unique id) in the newly created or previously created listing "someList" as well as the object in a 2D array. So for example, I might end up with this:

```
trace(_indexes["someList"][objectId]); // 0 - the object is the first in this list
trace(_instances["someList"]); // [object MyObject]
```

The class has another two methods:

1. `find(signature:String):Array`
   This method returns an array via `slice()` containing all of the elements signed with the given signature.
2. `findFirst(signature:String):Object`
   This method just returns the first object in a given listing

So to retrieve myObject I can either go:

`trace(find("someList")[0]);` `or` `trace(findFirst("someList"));`

Finally, there is an `unsign()` function which will remove an object from a given listing. This function basically:

1. Stores the result of `pop()` in the specified listing against a variable.
2. Uses the stored index to quickly replace the specified object with the `pop()`'d item.
3. Deletes the stored index for the specified object and updates the index for the `pop()`'d item.

Through all this, using `unsign()` will remove an object extremely quickly from a listing of any size.

Now this is all well and good, but I've had some thoughts which are making me consider how good this really is? I mean being able to easily list, remove and access lists of anything I want throughout the application like this is awesome - but is there a catch?

A couple of starting thoughts I have had are:

1. So far I haven't implemented support for listings that are private and only accessible via a given class.
2. Memory - this doesn't seem very memory efficient. Then again, neither is creating arrays for everything I want to store individually either. Just seems.. Larger.. Somehow.

Any insights?

I've uploaded the class here in case the above doesn't make much sense: https://projectavian.com/AviManager.as

Comment: sounds like you're over-engineering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems pretty solid. If you're looking to modify it to be a bit more extensible and handle rights management, you might consider moving all those individually indexed properties to a value object for your AV elements. You could perform operations like "sign" and "unsign" internally in the VOs, or check for access rights. Your management class could monitor the collection of these VOs, pass them around, perform the method calls, and the objects would hold the state in a bit more readable format.

Really, though, this is entering into a coding style discussion. Your method works and it's not particularly inefficient. Just make sure the code is readable, encapsulated, and extensible and you're good.

Comment: Actually that's an interesting solution. Have individual instances created within the application that handle sign, unsign, etc and act as the median between the signed object and the core manager. This means I could also specify whether the created listing will be accessible only within the class it's created or globally.